"RuntimeError: XS: No such file or directory" error while specifying the table when using the GeoPackage source dataset in ogrmerge
I am trying to merge specific tables of multiple GPKGs using ogrmerge. How to specify the table to use when in the source dataset name. When using ogrinfo we can do the following to work with XS table only.
ogrinfo "D:\\Users\\abdul.siddiqui\\workbench\\projects\\production\\source_models\\STEWARTS CREEK\\STEWARTS CREEK.gpkg" XS

The same does not work in ogrmerege:
ogrmerge -o merged.gpkg "D:\\Users\\abdul.siddiqui\\workbench\\projects\\production\\source_models\\STEWARTS CREEK\\STEWARTS CREEK.gpkg" XS
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\Scripts\ogrmerge.py", line 14, in <module>
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py", line 1213, in main
    return process(argv[1:])
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py", line 280, in process
    return ogrmerge(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo_utils\ogrmerge.py", line 1116, in ogrmerge
    src_ds = ogr.Open(src_dsname)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W\apps\Python39\lib\site-packages\osgeo\ogr.py", line 7484, in Open
    return _ogr.Open(*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError: XS: No such file or directory


We need to see the command line you are trying to use

I am using OSGeo4W shell

As documented https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html, ogrmerge is made to merge all layers from a dataset. It does not allow to select just one layer from the dataset.

takes as input several vector datasets, each of them having one or
several vector layers, and copies them into a target dataset

However, you can use a workaround and create a temporary input file that contains only the desired layer from the source GeoPackage. The temporary file can be a virtual VRT file https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/vrt.html#vector-vrt so there is no need to make a new physical copy of the layer.
In your case this vrt file, named for example as my_vrt.vrt, should work:
<OGRVRTDataSource>
  <OGRVRTLayer name="XS">
    <SrcDataSource relativeToVRT="0">D:\\Users\\abdul.siddiqui\\workbench\\projects\\production\\source_models\\STEWARTS CREEK\\STEWARTS CREEK.gpkg</SrcDataSource>
    <SrcLayer>XS</SrcLayer>
</OGRVRTLayer>

Instead of escaping backslashes D:\\Users\\... the Windows path can also be written with forward slashes D:/Users/..
Now you can run
ogrmerge -o merged.gpkg my_vrt.vrt

It should not be difficult to write vrt files for all source GeoPackages with a simple script.
